# Home server connection not working

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I am doing a home for me and some of my friends however I am having some issues and cant get access to minecraft server.

I am running it through windows server 2019 and on a windows 10 vm server starts up fine however I cant connect I can only connect localy I checked and is connected to the internet.

Port forwarding is working as I have tested it on my PC and it works. Any Ideas let me know

Comment: Can you be more specific and add some details?  Port forwarding where?  How is it working, you say you can't connect?  What works on your PC, access to the server, port forwarding?  How is the VM's network configured, external virtual switch?

Comment: So my server works like this

Sewrver setup / VM setup

Windows Server 2019 with Hyper-V installed -> Virtual switch on external -> Windows 10 VM. However I have tried the server as internal and still nothing






------------------------------------------------------------





Portforwarding

Portforwarding is Windows 10 VM -> 192.168.1.25 and forwarding 25565 (This is for a minecraft server)

However my PC portforward -> 192.168.1.155 and forwarding 25565 and this works so I can use my Public IP aka my ISP allocated address

Comment: You definitely want an external virtual switch.  Verify your firewall for your VM is allowing the port 25565 and that you're only trying to forward to one IP at a time.